# Predicting the variable's score using predictive analytics

Tags: predictive-modeling, time-series, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to predictive analytics but I am good at programming (like Spark, R).

I have 10 variables and I know their score's for over a long period of time. I want to know which variable will have high score in the future?

If it is a linear plot (plotted between score and time for a variable), we can extrapolate the values and find the max(future_score) among the 10 variables.

But the plot is non-linear (although continuous).

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us some plots of them ? it really depends on what they look. There is a lot of temporal series forecast.

It will depends on :

- Is there any seasonality ?
- Is there a trend ?
- Is there a high volatility ?
- On how long do you want do to your forecast ?

Answer (score 1):

Exciting stuff that you're getting into! You may find this video helpful about [Predictive Analytics and its fundamentals](http://www.decisivedata.net/blog/what-is-predictive-analytics).

They offer a ton of helpful insight on predictive analytics fundamentals and how predictive analytics fit into the spectrum of analytics and data science.

Hopefully, this will help clarify!

Best Wishes, Bethany